# How to compare ArrayList with SQLite Table Row?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

Let's say I have a sqlite table named "table" with the rows id, text1, text2

now I have an ArrayList with the content, let's say:

- id:0,text1:this is the first text,text2: this is the second text
- id:21, text1: blabla, text2: blabla2
  ...

now i want to make a comparision between sqlite row and every single element row in arraylist.
for example i want to say delete every row in sqlite table which is not equal with any row in arraylist.

I could not find any equal thread that contains my question.. maybe you can help me or give me some link. thank u

Answer (score 2):

Here you have some example code. You should get the idea:

```
public void removeRows(DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter, ArrayList<SomeObject> list) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbAdapter.openWritableDatabase();
    Cursor rows = db.query(/ *perform some query on SQLite db*/);
    while(rows.moveToNext()) {
        int id = rows.getInt(0);
        String text1 = rows.getString(1);
        String text2 = rows.getString(2);
        boolean included = false;
        for(SomeObject obj : list) {
            if(obj.getId() == id && obj.getText1().equals(text1) && obj.getText2().equals(text2)) {
                included = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!included) {
            db.delete(/*perform deletion of row*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: To add to database those objects from list which are not yet in it do something like this:

```
public void addListToDb(DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter, ArrayList<SomeObject> list) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbAdapter.openWritableDatabase(); 
    Cursor rows = db.query(/ *perform some query on SQLite db*/);
    for(SomeObject obj : list) {
        boolean included = false;
        while(rows.moveToNext()) {
            int id = rows.getInt(0);
            String text1 = rows.getString(1);
            String text2 = rows.getString(2);
            if(obj.getId() == id && obj.getText1().equals(text1) && obj.getText2().equals(text2)) {
                included = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        rows.moveToPosition(-1);
        if(!included) {
            db.insert(/*perform insert of object*/);
        }
    }
}
```

There is also another way to accomplish this task. Loop over elements of your list and add every element to database using `SQLiteDatabase#insertWithOnConflict(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues initialValues, int conflictAlgorithm)` method and pass SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE as a conflictAlgorithm. Above method will add element if it not yet exists in database. Otherwise it will ignore it. Important thing to remember is that when we try to insert a row which already exists in database with CONFLICT_IGNORE conflict algorithm we will get -1 result instead of primary key of existing row (Android documentation is misleading here).

Comment: Yes it worked.. How could I look If any list array is already in sqlite.. If No then add the array into sqlite

Comment: I will edit answer to show you the way, but actually the main idea is quite similar.